# Automatic creation of Gazebo world

Tags: gazebo-world

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is there the possibility of create a Gazebo world from a map created with gmapping(.pgm image) automatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2835/automatic-creation-of-gazebo-world/) by [camilla](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/150/camilla/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can create a heightmap from an image file. The drcsim repository has several example heightmaps:

vrc_heightmap_1: [sdf file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/949f1b635de1/gazebo_models/environments/vrc_heightmap_1/model.sdf?at=default), [image file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/949f1b635de1b2841619ea4407a8bbea580c34fd/gazebo_models/environments/vrc_heightmap_1/materials/textures/heightmap.png?at=default)

vrc_heightmap_2: [sdf file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/949f1b635de1/gazebo_models/environments/vrc_heightmap_2/model.sdf?at=default), [image file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/949f1b635de1b2841619ea4407a8bbea580c34fd/gazebo_models/environments/vrc_heightmap_2/materials/textures/heightmap.png?at=default)

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0